# Using Polymer in priviledged Firefox OS

Tags: web-applications, polymer, firefox-os, content-security-policy

I'm developing a small webapp for Firefox OS using [Polymer](http://polymer-project.org). Everything is working properlery, until I set the webapp's type in the manifest to "priviledged". Then, Polymer isn't computed. There's an error in the console:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8...
```

Am I not allowed to load external scripts? Or do I something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Privileged apps are packaged apps that needs to be signed by a trusted party (Firefox Marketplace so far) and all its code is supposed to be contained in the app package. So you cannot load external scripts from a privileged app.

Check the [CSP documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manifest#csp). Note the `script-src 'self';` part.

You'll need to put Polymer scripts inside you app's package.

If you are just testing locally and you are not planning to distribute your app, you can disable the CSP restrictions by setting this preference in your device:

```
pref("security.apps.privileged.CSP.default", "default-src *; script-src *; object-src 'none'; style-src *");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I don't load code from outside my webapp. These scripts are almost all located in inline <script>-Tags. The whole html files are loaded.

Comment: Inline scripts are also considered unsafe for privileged apps. Note the 'unsafe-inline' bit on the CSP documentation for privileged apps.

Comment: I read sometihng about a tool called vulcanize (which is from Polymer, too). It basically is a "compiler" for the html – it performs all <link rel="import" />s and puts the result in a new html file, the "compiled" one. That'd probably solve my problem.